# Ordering Rails Array of Json's by the key "updated_at" 's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to order an array of jsons by a value.

I cannot just query the database with `.order('created_at DESC')` because my array is filled with information from 2 different tables.

Here is the code that I  have so far:

```
@user_items = UserItem.where(user_id: @friends.to_a).order('created_at DESC')
@user_pics = Pic.where(user_id: @friends.to_a).order('created_at DESC')
@all_things = @user_pics + @user_items
@all_things.sort_by{"updated_at"}
```

This does not error but when I run the code the first things in the list are always all the pictures followed by all the items. So, it seems the list line of code is doing nothing.

Here is a sample of what `user_pics[0]` looks like:

`{"id"=>15, "user_id"=>2, "name"=>"New titles", "creator"=>nil, "size"=>nil, "created_at"=>Sun, 14 Feb 2016 02:41:12 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sun, 14 Feb 2016 02:41:12 UTC +00:00 ...}`

EDIT 1

Sadly, the suggested answer does not seem to be working. Below are a few different outputs. Firstly, a pic that was updated Feb 14, then items that were updated Feb 24 and Feb 13 respectively. It seems the array is still ordered with all pictures first then all items.

> > @all_things.sort_by { |a| a[:updated_at] } [0]
> >     => {"id"=>15, "user_id"=>2, "name"=>"New titles", "creator"=>nil, "size"=>nil, "mark_count"=>nil, "created_at"=>Sun, 14 Feb 2016 02:41:12 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sun, 14 Feb 2016 02:41:12 UTC +00:00 ... }
> >
> > @all_things.sort_by { |a| a[:updated_at] } [4]
> >     => {"id"=>846, "item_id"=>669, "user_id"=>2, "created_at"=>Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:43:54 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 24 Feb 2016 16:43:54 UTC +00:00, ...}
> >
> > @all_things.sort_by { |a| a[:updated_at] } [50]
> >     => {"id"=>797, "item_id"=>623, "user_id"=>2, "created_at"=>Sat, 13 Feb 2016 03:58:29 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Sat, 13 Feb 2016 03:58:29 UTC +00:00, ...}

Comment: Are `@all_things` and `@all_feed_cards` the same thing?

Comment: @kjprice yes, sorry fixed it (code still doesn't work though)

Comment: It might be that the Hash you have is using strings as the keys, not symbols. Give `a["updated_at"]` a try, that might be of help here

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just calling `#sort_by` incorrectly:

```
 @all_things.sort_by { |thing| thing["updated_at"] }
```

Since you're sorting by datetime strings, you can parse them into DateTime objects:

```
 @all_things.sort_by { |thing| DateTime.httpdate(thing["updated_at"]) }
```

I'd like to suggest as well, that this might be a design problem. For this specific problem of union'ing two classes, you could consider single-table inheritance.

Comment: Each of these lines returns a `!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method ``updated_at' for #<Hash:0xb80af74>>` for me

Comment: Hmm, it wasn't clear to me if you were sorting ActiveRecord objects or the JSON. Updated my answer for JSON.

Comment: I have tried your answer but it seems to have no effect on the ouput. See edit 1

Answer (score 0):

You are using the sort in the worng way. Try with that:

> @all_things.sort_by { |a| a[:updated_at] }

Comment: That returns a '!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method ``updated_at' for #<Hash:0xb80af74>>' for me